# Why for-each loop does not allow increment Integer?

Tags: java, foreach, integer

I mean in this code:

```
List<Integer> list = new LinkedList();
list.add(1);
list.add(2);
list.add(3);

for (Integer i : list)
    i++;

System.out.println(list.get(0))
```

returns 1 not 2. In for-each loop Java creates new object (i) and copies fields value from object in List?

Comment: the question makes a good joke :)

Answer (score 9, accepted):

`Integer`s are immutable.

Your code changes the `i` variable to point to a brand-new `Integer` instance with a larger value.

The original `Integer` instance in the list is not (and cannot be) changed.

Comment: I forgot that `Integer` objects are immutable. what a pity

Comment: @rll: It's actually a very, very, very good thing that `Integer` objects are immutable!

Comment: just a nitpick, `instance with a larger value`, could a lesser one as well :)

Comment: @rll: Otherwise, arbitrary `Integer` objects could change behind your back.

Comment: @rll: For one thing, it's consistent with `int` primitives... if you pass an `int` to some method, it can't change the value of the `int` that you're using without you knowing. The same is true for `Integer` objects. Think of it like this... the value "1" should always be the value "1". "1" can't just become "3". If you want "3", you need to get the value "3"... which is a different and distinct object. It's logical for an object representing such a value to be unable to change, in addition to the practical advantages of not having to worry about code elsewhere changing values under your feet.

Comment: Yes, the same result would be with a `int[]` and `int` as variable type.

Answer (score 9):

the ++ operator is not a valid operator on the Integer object, so Java uses it's auto-boxing features to convert the Integer object into an int primitive.  Once it's converted, the int primitive is incremented.  You don't save the primitive so it is lost.

To achieve the goal you need to do something like

```
List<Integer> list = new LinkedList();
list.add(1);
list.add(2);
list.add(3);


for (int index; index < list.size(); index++) {
   int value = list.get(index).intValue();
   value++;
   list.set(index, Integer.valueOf(value));
}

System.out.println(list.get(0))
```

The code above is not optimal; but it doesn't use autoboxing.  An optimized solution would use a ListIterator (added by popular demand) :^)

```
ListIterator<Integer> iterator = list.iterator();
while (iterator.hasNext()) {
  iterator.set(iterator.get()++);
}
```

Note that this loop uses autoboxing heavily, if you wish to get an idea of what autoboxing is doing under the covers, the equivalent solution presented below doesn't rely on any autoboxing.

```
ListIterator<Integer> iterator = list.iterator();
while (iterator.hasNext()) {
  iterator.set(Integer.valueOf(iterator.get().intValue()++));
}
```

Comment: `++` **is** a valid operator on `Integer` and it modifies the variable to reference a `Integer` that is one higher than the previous one. The real reason this doesn't work is that `Integer` is immutable and `++` only creates a new version.

Comment: No, the "Object i" which has a Type of Integer never gets incremented.  If it did, then there would be a method called on "Object i" and "++" is not a method.  "Object i" gets converted into "primitive i" due to auto-boxing, and "primitive i" gets incremented.  This leaves "Object i" untouched.

Comment: @Edwin: You should try it. `i++` on an object `Integer i` assigns `i` to an `Integer` object with a value 1 greater than the original value of `i`. If you mean that the original object itself isn't modified, that is of course true since it's immutable.

Comment: @ColinD, It isn't that it won't compile, or that it won't return a value one greater, it's that you're misattributing the operation ++ to the Integer.  Autoboxing converts the Integer to an int first because there's no "public int "++"() { ... }" method in Integer.

Comment: @Edwin: Well, I don't think anyone was saying there is such a method. However, using `++` on an `Integer` variable in practice does exactly the same thing as converting it to an `int`, then incrementing that `int`, then using `Integer.valueOf` to convert that back to an `Integer` and finally reassigning the original variable, so I think it's generally preferable to just use `++` rather than doing all that work manually. If your issue is just with the wording "`++` is a valid operator on `Integer`", I think that's valid too since it works and does exactly what one would expect.

Comment: At least use `ListIteator.set()` for `LinkedList`

Comment: @bestsss, sure thing.  Just didn't want to steal any wind from Peter Lawrey's sails.  ListIterators are a better way of changing a List, but that's orthogonal to the actual issue that ++ is a primitive operator.

Comment: @Edwin Buck, I, myself, almost never use `(int i=0;s=l.size();i<s;i++)` construct

Comment: @bestsss, it's a coding style I still have from earlier days.  It has it's advantages, depending on the situation.  Namely it doesn't require extra JVM frames to get the next element, which can speed up items in some situations.  That said, a single typo and you're off to la-la land.

Answer (score 7):

It does allow it, it doesn't do what you think it does.

What you have is shorthand for.

```
for (Iterator<Integer> iter = list.iterator(); iter.hashNext();) {
    Integer i = iter.next();
    i++; // value is discarded after this line.
}
```

EDIT: rather than using get(i) and set(i, value) which can be very expensive for LinkedList, a better choice would be to use ListIterator.

```
for (ListIterator<Integer> iter = list.listIterator(); iter.hasNext();)
    iter.set(iter.next()+1);
```

Comment: Otherwise the LinkedList has to tranverse the list from the start every time to find & set the n-th element.

Comment: Nice optimization.  I like the list iterator.

Comment: The fastest way to do this is using TIntArrayList.increment(n) or int[] with ++ as they use primitive values.

Answer (score 0):

Because the 0th element in the list is the "1", which you added in line 2.

Oh, I understand: You want to increment the integers. You have to do:

```
for( int i=0; i<list.size(); i++ ) {
    list.set(i,list.get(i)+1);
}
```

Please note that Integer instances are immutable. The value cannot change!

Comment: should use list iterator now it's O(n*n)

Comment: You are right. I didn't note the LinkedList, thought it was an ArrayList.

Answer (score 0):

Because `Integer` is immutable, just like `String`, etc.

The operator `++` on an integer is just like doing :

```
i = new Integer(i.intValue()+1);`
```

You'll need to `list.set(index, i);` to modify the value in your list.

```
for (int index=0; index<list.size(); index++) {
   list.set(index, list.get(index)+1);
}
```

Comment: And you should not call `set()` like that in the loop. If you need to loop over a collection and modify it in that loop, you need to use an explicit `Iterator`.

Comment: Using `new Integer()` is more expensive than using auto-boxing as the later uses a cache of Integer's (and its longer to write/read)

Comment: @Peter, actually `Integer.valueOf(int)` is kind of controversial, it makes the JVM unable to optimize the code b/c it's not sure if the allocation is going to happen or not (it works only for -128 - +127 which is quite limited). In that particular case the allocation 'escapes' but in others it doesn't and new Integer() would have been just as fine (or better)

Comment: Running some simple tests, I don't see any evidence that `Integer.valueOf()` is optimised any less than `new Integer()`

Comment: @bestsss, I have found one micro-benchmark where new Integer() saves 300 ns; when the objects are always discarded.  In the case of using `n++`, using valueOf was about 200 ns faster. Such micro-benchamrks are very sensitive to what else you are trying to do.

Comment: @Joachim, yes, this was to explain how `++` work with an `Integer` object. I updated my answer to specify how to increment the list's value at index `index`

Comment: @Peter, micro-benchmarks are hard to please and can be sort of biased. The main concern is: if the Integer doesn't escape the stack, it can be beneficial to just go w/ new Integer() [the final field value doesn't help much, though], if the instance escapes (and/or cannot be optimized) valueOf() will be an ok solution. I just dont consider it big issue optimization-wise (and I, myself, still use larger look up table ~8192 dating back in 1.1days). Integers are the most boxed in/out classes, so less memory footprint is good.

Comment: Byte is the ideal for autoboxing, but not used so often. ;)

Comment: @Peter, so is Boolean (personal favorite, but deserialization sucks)

Answer (score 0):

Since all the answers are about immutability, here how it would look with a mutable type:

```
import java.util.concurrent.AtomicInteger;


List<AtomicInteger> list = new LinkedList<AtomicInteger>();
list.add(new AtomicInteger(1));
list.add(new AtomicInteger(2));
list.add(new AtomicInteger(3));

for (AtomicInteger i : list)
    i.getAndIncrement();

System.out.println(list.get(0));
```

This should output `2`. (AtomicInteger additionally has these thread-safety properties, but we need here only the mutability.)

The primitive type `int` (as all primitives) is immutable, too, so the following variant would still output `1`:

```
int[] list = new int[]{ 1, 2, 3};

for (int i : list)
    i++;

System.out.println(list[0]);
```